# git-p4 max-changes option imports history from beginning instead of last revisions

Tags: git, perforce

./git p4 clone --destination=/test-project --max-changes=5 //test/content@all

Returns first five changes in project instead of last 5 changes.

Is there a way to import just the last 5 changes. According to the git-documentation it should be importing the most recent history and not starting from the beginning.

I tested this on git 2.6.2

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The documentation just says:

> Limit the number of imported changes to n. Useful to limit the amount of history when using the @all p4 revision specifier.

And the code itself just uses this to limit the set of changes to *0..maxChanges*, rather than *totalChanges-maxChanges..totalChanges* which I guess is what you're looking for. I agree though that the documentation is certainly ambiguous.

What ought to work though is to just specify the revision range explicitly. For example, if your highest revision number is 100, and you only want 10 changes, then I think this should work:

```
$ git p4 clone //depot/somebranch/...@90
$ cd somebranch
$ git p4 sync
```

Comment: smart! i have been looking for this for 2 days